# nested aggregations filtering

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have my document indexed with locations nested,

```
{
  "name": "name 1",
  "locations": [
     { 
       "region": "region1",
       "city": "city1",
       "suburb": "suburb1"
     },
     { 
       "region": "region2",
       "city": "city2",
       "suburb": "suburb2"
      },
      {
        region": "region1",
       "city": "city5",
       "suburb": "suburb4"
      }]
}
```

I have my query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "locations",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "locations.region.keyword": {
                    "value": "region1"
                   }
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

I want aggregate only cities for `region1`. I've tried `nested` aggregations, `nested` with `filter` aggregations, and with `reverse` nested. Nothing seems to work. The problem is since documents come with other regions in the `locations` collection, everything get aggregated even cities that don't belong to `region1`.

any ideas?

**EDIT**:

Mappings:

```
"my_index": {
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "locations": {
          "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "city": {
                "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                       "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "region": {
                  "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "suburb": {
                    "type": "text",
                      "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }  
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                      "type": "keyword",
                      "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "locations.region.keyword": [
                  "region1"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "path": "locations"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "City": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "locations"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "City": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "locations.city.keyword",
            "size": 100,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_term": "asc"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggs": {
            "City": {
              "reverse_nested": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what the mapping looks like for your type i.e. what does `GET {index}/{type}/_mapping` return?

Comment: updated to include the mappings and my example query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your mapping is correct as per your usage in the query

You may  use the below mentioned query to use filters in your aggregation.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "city_agg": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "locations"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "filter_locations_regions": {
                    "filter": {
                        "term": {
                            "locations.region.keyword": "region1"
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "cities_in_region_agg": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "locations.city.keyword",
                                "size": 100,
                                "order": [{
                                        "_count": "desc"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "_term": "asc"
                                    }]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm about to try it. I just wanted to give that extra info first in case you wanted to change it before I try it.

Comment: works. but count nested document instead. I should add that I want to count the root documents.

Comment: for that, you can use reverse_nested aggregation like you have used in your query. Let me know if that doesn't work.